# How would Rolle's Theorem be used to prove this?

Tags: real-analysis

g is differentiable on (a,b) and for all x in [a,b]

$a<g(x)<b$, and $|g'(x)|<1/2$.

Prove $g(x)=x$ has at most one solution in [a,b]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g(x)=x$ has two solutions $x_1,x_2$ in $[a,b]$. By the mean value theorem we know that there exists $c\in [x_1,x_2]$ such that:

$$g'(c)=\frac{g(x_2)-g(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=1$$

This is a contradiction because $|g'|<0.5$